# Trigger click function in area of map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using map, code is below

```
<map name="shotBoxLeftRight" onMouseOut="clearImage('two');">
    <area shape="circle" coords="24,24,12" href="#HIT" title="HIT" alt="HIT" onClick="clickShotBox($(this).attr('alt'),'two');" onMouseOver="mouseOverShotBox($(this).attr('alt'),'two');"/>
    <area shape="poly" coords="48,0,24,24,48,48" href="#RIGHT" title="RIGHT" onClick="clickShotBox($(this).attr('alt'),'two');" alt="RIGHT" onMouseOver="mouseOverShotBox($(this).attr('alt'),'two');"/>
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,48,24,24,0,0" href="#LEFT" title="LEFT" alt="LEFT" onClick="clickShotBox($(this).attr('alt'),'two');" onMouseOver="mouseOverShotBox($(this).attr('alt'),'two');"/>
</map>
```

How i can trigger function `"clickShotBox($(this).attr('alt'),'two')"` in the area with parameter  using Click Event. This map is using three areas - LEFT, RIGHT, and HIT. 
How i can track a hit of specific area with JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change this to:

```
clickShotBox($(this).attr('alt'),'two')
```

To:

```
clickShotBox($(this).attr('alt','two'))
```

**Note:** Avoid using inline javascript as it causes difficult in maintainability and it becomes tedious job for a new programmer to understand the code.